# How do I add or switch to a Linux server

Tags: linux

I currently have a Windows server.  I need a Linux server in order to make the website I am working on.  How do I do this?

Comment: That's really vague. Do you want to install and run your own server, or do you want to pay for a hosted solution?

Answer (score 6):

Options:

1. Get a computer. [Get a Linux install disc](http://debian.org/distrib/). Put them together
2. As 1, but use a virtual machine (such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)) instead of a computer
3. Find an Internet hosting or VM provider and rent the server

Comment: In option 2. The existing Windows server could host a Virtual Linux server.  There is also an option 4. Install typical Linux tools (Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl) on the Windows server.

Comment: Yes, I thought I implied it in my answer, but it is good to be specific.

Comment: Note that a lot of Linux distro's are now available to run-from-cd which allows you to try out any hardware compatibility issues before you install. NB I'm not suggesting that this is likely to be more of a problem than upgrading MSWindows - actually IME, its a lot easier, and this allows you to find out **before** you trash your existing OS!

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to replace wholesale your existing Windows server software with Linux or are you interested in running a virtual Linux server from within your current Windows system?

If the former, will the server be headless (without a keyboard and display) or will it include a desktop environment?

If the (former) latter, you may be interested in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/)